# Getting all Facebook pages issue

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to write a python program that retrieves all Facebook pages and their likes count in order to find the most liked Facebook page. The problem is that I can't find out how to get all Facebook pages (not just the pages I liked but all Facebook pages) I have searched this problem but till now I could not figure a solution yet. What I figured out that I can get only the pages I liked not all Facebook pages. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?
What is the specific field I must put in my query in order to get all Facebook pages?

```
import facebook
import json

def pp(o): 
    print json.dumps(o, indent=1)

ACCESS_TOKEN = ''#access token here

g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)


pp(g.get_object(#what to put here)) # I did not know what to put here in order to get all Facebook pages
```

Comment: Any attempts that you'd like to share?

Comment: _“not just the pages I liked but all Facebook pages”_ – you are aware that there’s gonna be probably hundred thousands or more of those? Looping through all of those would take forever … and besides, there is no API that gives those to you anyway.

Comment: @CBroe: yup I am aware of that but I am gonna to take only pages in English language but the problem that I only retrieved pages I liked and I want all English pages on Facebook in order to find most liked one. do you have any idea because I am stuck  at this point and I am badly need help .

Answer (score 3):

**1)** For getting the pages for which the user is admin of, you have to send `GET` request to :

https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Here the `ACCESS_TOKEN` will be the token of the user.

Use:

```
  pages = g.get_connections("me", "accounts")
```

**2)** For getting the pages liked by the user you have to send `GET` request to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Use:

```
 pages = g.get_connections("me", "likes")
```

**Edit:** To get the names and ids of the pages, you have to parse the response like this:

```
for pg in pages['data']:
print pg['id'] + ' ' + pg['name']
```

Comment: OK but what if I want only the title of the page how to get this field?